# Replace specific value based on condition in a loop pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, dataframe

EDITED :

I want to replace a value in a cell if values on other cells satisfy the condition

Currently, I have this

```
   for a in ACPurchased:
        aPos = self.model.grid.get_cell_list_contents(a.pos)
        CustAC = [a for a in aPos if a.breed =='AC']

        for b in CustAC:
            AC_Data = [b.AC,b.Appliance,b.COP]

            self.AC_DataPOS[self.AC_DataPOS['Category'].isin(AC_Data) &
                            self.AC_DataPOS['Appliance'].isin(AC_Data) &
                            self.AC_DataPOS['COP'].isin(AC_Data),
                            'Status'] = 'occupied'
```

And return to this error:

```
File"/Users/widhadyah/Dropbox/MyPythonProject/ePSSMaterialModel/src/MaterialModel.py", line 275, in UpdateUsedMachineStatus
        'Status'] = 'occupied'
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2419, in __setitem__
        self._set_item(key, value)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2485, in _set_item
        value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2684, in _sanitize_column
        if broadcast and key in self.columns and value.ndim == 1:
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 1393, in __contains__
        hash(key)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 831, in __hash__
        ' hashed'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
    TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

I have tried to using .iterrows() and still getting the same error.
Any advice on this problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you please [edit] and add the full exception details? You code is not syntactically correct missing a `]` somewhere - you will need to fix that.

Comment: I think need `loc` and add `()` like `self.AC_DataPOS.loc[(self.AC_DataPOS['COP']== b.COP) &
                                (self.AC_DataPOS['Appl'] == b.App),
                                'Status'] = 'occupied'`

Comment: @jezrael it works!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think need [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) because chain filtering by boolean mask and selecting column `Status`:

```
self.AC_DataPOS.loc[self.AC_DataPOS['Category'].isin(AC_Data) &
                            self.AC_DataPOS['Appliance'].isin(AC_Data) &
                            self.AC_DataPOS['COP'].isin(AC_Data),
                            'Status'] = 'occupied'
```